# RegEx to - if string not between quotes add quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

Finding trouble in getting the following regex work to put the string between quotes:

```
"\"mytext\"".replaceAll("^\"?|\"?$", "\"")
```

The above code gives - `"mytext""` as the output, but what I require is `"mytext"`.

For troubleshooting, I replaced the replaceWith character to * and the output is - `*mytext**`

Why is `\"?$` considered as two separate matches?

Comment: FYI, you may use a regex to actually remove `"` chars at the start/end with `.replaceAll("^\"+|\"+$", "")`, and then add quotes. If you want to practice regex you may use a single `replaceAll("(?s)^\"*(.*?)\"*$", "\"$1\"")` call.

Comment: You are welcome. Mind that empty string matching patterns in regex `replace` methods are rather tricky, you should really know what you are doing when using them.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the tip @WiktorStribiżew!